# MYSQL Events syntax error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running this CREATE EVENT query below, and it does create an event, but if I go in and look at the syntax in Edit Event I see a red x for END but no explanation.  Therefore the event is not running, what do I have wrong?  Thanks for the help in advance:

```
DELIMITER !
 CREATE EVENT providers_import ON SCHEDULE EVERY 9 DAY_HOUR
 ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
 COMMENT 'providers_old copied'
 DO
  BEGIN
   DROP TABLE providers_old ;
   CREATE TABLE providers_old LIKE providers ;
   INSERT INTO providers_old SELECT * FROM providers GROUP BY Provider_Last_Name ;
  END !
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You haven't said what program this question is about (the script runs fine in the official command-line client).

Comment: The title says MYSQL events, but to further clarify this is in phpMyAdmin I am seeing this.

Comment: Yes the script does run fine, but when I go to view the details I see this https://i.imgur.com/g17yPJr.png

Comment: **Solved**
I had spaces at the end my line between the last word and ;

Comment: The screenshot in your comment shows completely different code...

Comment: Yes because after running the above query to add an event, that is what the event viewer plugin shows in phpMyAdmin.  Have you ever used that product?